# Drupal apache solr org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error initializing QueryElevationComponent

Tags: 7, search

I have set up apache solr for drupal

i am using solr4.7.2 and latest drupal apache solr module

i have setup everything but in solr panel i get this error

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error initializing QueryElevationComponent.

i think this is becuase of the code in solrconfig.xml

```
<searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >
<!-- pick a fieldType to analyze queries -->
<str name="queryFieldType">string</str>
<str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
```

but this code is provided by apachesolr module of drupal

i don't know what this code does or required or not. I spent hours but couldn't resolve it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The error is most likely nothing to do with Drupal, I'm using the latest version of that module with solr 4.7, 4.8 and 4.9 on various machines and they all work fine with the out-of-the-box config

Comment: i get this error only when i place drupal's solrconfig.xml. Can you provide me your solrconfig.xml

Comment: I use the one that comes with the module (the same one you're using). That's why the problem is likely not to be with Drupal, but with your SOLR server